# Validate TLS certificate c#

Tags: c#, ssl, https, certificate

I'm trying to connect to a public administration http server but it launch an AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
So how can i validate the SSL connection? i have the .cer file of the remote htpps SERVER.

```
public RestClient(string baseAddress)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        //handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidateRemoteCertificate;
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }

    private bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate? certificate, X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors || chain is null || certificate is null)
        {
            // Name mismatch or no cert
            return false;
        }

        chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
        chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(new X509Certificate2("CAServizioAECorrispettiviIVA.cer"));
        chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(new X509Certificate2("CAServizioAECorrispettiviIVA.cer"));
        bool value = chain.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: First, validate that your certificate has not been revoked by the issuer.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Follow this tutorial if you have the certificate: https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/utility-test-ocsp-and-crl-access-from-a-server.htm#:~:text=To%20check%20the%20revocation%20status,it%20hasn't%20been%20revoked. So you will know if your certificate has been revoked.